MeCab doesnt seem to return correct response
So i just installed MeCab and tried to run it in node.
i took example from this url https://github.com/hecomi/node-mecab-async#readme to check if i installed it properly but i guess something went wrong.
i tried to run the example from documentation
var MeCab = new require('mecab-async')
  , mecab = new MeCab()
;
mecab.parse('いつもニコニコあなたの隣に這い寄る混沌ニャルラトホテプです！', function(err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(result);
});

the result should be
[ [ 'いつも', '副詞', '一般', '*', '*', '*', '*', 'いつも', 'イツモ', 'イツモ' ],
  [ 'ニコニコ', '副詞', '助詞類接続', '*', '*', '*', '*', 'ニコニコ', 'ニコニコ', 'ニコニコ' ],
  [ 'あなた', '名詞', '代名詞', '一般', '*', '*', '*', 'あなた', 'アナタ', 'アナタ' ],
  [ 'の', '助詞', '連体化', '*', '*', '*', '*', 'の', 'ノ', 'ノ' ],
  [ '隣', '名詞', '一般', '*', '*', '*', '*', '隣', 'トナリ', 'トナリ' ],
  [ 'に', '助詞', '格助詞', '一般', '*', '*', '*', 'に', 'ニ', 'ニ' ],
  [ '這い', '動詞', '自立', '*', '*', '五段・ワ行促音便', '連用形', '這う', 'ハイ', 'ハイ' ],
  [ '寄る', '動詞', '自立', '*', '*', '五段・ラ行', '基本形', '寄る', 'ヨル', 'ヨル' ],
  [ '混沌', '名詞', '一般', '*', '*', '*', '*', '混沌', 'コントン', 'コントン' ],
  [ 'ニャルラトホテプ', '名詞', '一般', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*' ],
  [ 'です', '助動詞', '*', '*', '*', '特殊・デス', '基本形', 'です', 'デス', 'デス' ],
  [ '！', '記号', '一般', '*', '*', '*', '*', '！', '！', '！' ] ]

but what i get is
[
  [ '?', '名詞', 'サ変接続', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*\r' ],
  [ '?', '名詞', 'サ変接続', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*\r' ],
  [ '?', '名詞', 'サ変接続', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*\r' ],
  [ '?', '名詞', 'サ変接続', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*\r' ],
  [ '?', '名詞', 'サ変接続', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*\r' ],
  [
    '????????????????????????!',
    '名詞',
    'サ変接続',
    '*',
    '*',
    '*',
    '*',
    '*\r'
  ]
]

does anyone have any idea what i might be doing wrong here?

This is most likely happening because you have a different MeCab dictionary than what node-mecab-async is expecting. If you run
echo いつもニコニコあなたの隣に這い寄る混沌ニャルラトホテプです！ | mecab

what do you get? I'm guessing it'll have a lot of ? question marks like is output by your script.
You can get information on what dictionary MeCab is using by running mecab -D, and you can select which MeCab dictionary to use by mecab -d /path/to/dictionary/directory. Each dictionary has its own output format, so you need to ensure MeCab is using the same dictionary that your tooling expects.
node-mecab-async seems to expect IPAdic. After I followed the installation directions here https://github.com/neologd/mecab-ipadic-neologd I ran the following command to confirm it's what node-mecab-async expects:
$ echo いつもニコニコあなたの隣に這い寄る混沌ニャルラトホテプです！ | mecab -d /opt/homebrew/lib/mecab/dic/mecab-ipadic-neologd
いつも 副詞,一般,*,*,*,*,いつも,イツモ,イツモ
ニコニコ    副詞,助詞類接続,*,*,*,*,ニコニコ,ニコニコ,ニコニコ
あなた 名詞,代名詞,一般,*,*,*,あなた,アナタ,アナタ
の   助詞,連体化,*,*,*,*,の,ノ,ノ
隣   名詞,一般,*,*,*,*,隣,トナリ,トナリ
に   助詞,格助詞,一般,*,*,*,に,ニ,ニ
這い  動詞,自立,*,*,五段・ワ行促音便,連用形,這う,ハイ,ハイ
寄る  動詞,自立,*,*,五段・ラ行,基本形,寄る,ヨル,ヨル
混沌  名詞,一般,*,*,*,*,混沌,コントン,コントン
ニャルラトホテプ    名詞,固有名詞,一般,*,*,*,ニャルラトホテプ,ニャルラトホテプ,ニャルラトホテプ
です  助動詞,*,*,*,特殊・デス,基本形,です,デス,デス
！   記号,一般,*,*,*,*,！,！,！
EOS

Having confirmed that the raw MeCab output is what I expect, I tweaked the node-mecab-async command to use this dictionary:
var MeCab = new require("mecab-async"),
  mecab = new MeCab();
mecab.command =
  "/opt/homebrew/bin/mecab -d /opt/homebrew/lib/mecab/dic/mecab-ipadic-neologd";

mecab.parse(
  "いつもニコニコあなたの隣に這い寄る混沌ニャルラトホテプです！",
  function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(result);
  }
);

This outputs:
[
  [
    'いつも', '副詞',
    '一般',   '*',
    '*',      '*',
    '*',      'いつも',
    'イツモ', 'イツモ'
  ],
  [
    'ニコニコ',   '副詞',
    '助詞類接続', '*',
    '*',          '*',
    '*',          'ニコニコ',
    'ニコニコ',   'ニコニコ'
  ],
  [
    'あなた', '名詞',
    '代名詞', '一般',
    '*',      '*',
    '*',      'あなた',
    'アナタ', 'アナタ'
  ],
  [
    'の',     '助詞',
    '連体化', '*',
    '*',      '*',
    '*',      'の',
    'ノ',     'ノ'
  ],
  [
    '隣',     '名詞',
    '一般',   '*',
    '*',      '*',
    '*',      '隣',
    'トナリ', 'トナリ'
  ],
  [
    'に',     '助詞',
    '格助詞', '一般',
    '*',      '*',
    '*',      'に',
    'ニ',     'ニ'
  ],
  [ '這い', '動詞', '自立', '*', '*', '五段・ワ行促音便', '連用形', '這う', 'ハイ', 'ハイ' ],
  [
    '寄る',   '動詞',
    '自立',   '*',
    '*',      '五段・ラ行',
    '基本形', '寄る',
    'ヨル',   'ヨル'
  ],
  [
    '混沌',     '名詞',
    '一般',     '*',
    '*',        '*',
    '*',        '混沌',
    'コントン', 'コントン'
  ],
  [
    'ニャルラトホテプ',
    '名詞',
    '固有名詞',
    '一般',
    '*',
    '*',
    '*',
    'ニャルラトホテプ',
    'ニャルラトホテプ',
    'ニャルラトホテプ'
  ],
  [
    'です',   '助動詞',
    '*',      '*',
    '*',      '特殊・デス',
    '基本形', 'です',
    'デス',   'デス'
  ],
  [
    '！', '記号', '一般',
    '*',  '*',    '*',
    '*',  '！',   '！',
    '！'
  ]
]

which I think is what we expect.
So tldr,

Install IPADic or it's modern equivalent, https://github.com/neologd/mecab-ipadic-neologd
If you use mecab-ipadic-neologd then tweak your mecab.command as above: mecab.command = "/path/to/mecab -d /path/to/mecab-ipadic-neologd"

(Tip. I'm on macOS and unfortunately brew install mecab-ipadic does't seem to work: I get garbled output. Maybe it's not a UTF-8-compatible dictionary? So I recommend mecab-ipadic-neologd.)
(Shameless promotion. If you try Unidic and you decide you like that dictionary—I've been using Unidic with MeCab for a while and have a pretty complete Node wrapper for it. It's part of a larger package but I think this file should be pretty stand-alone: https://github.com/fasiha/curtiz-japanese-nlp/blob/master/mecabUnidic.ts)

thanks for help, you helped, it was the matter of wrong dictionary!
